# Navigate to specific fragments with navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

I currently have this `nav_graph.xml` file.

Activity A (parent container), with this navigation tree:

Fragment A -> Fragment B -> Fragment C -> Fragment D -> Fragment E.

Also, I have an Activity B, and I want to navigate directly to Fragment C from this activity.

Does anyone know how I can realize an elegant solution for this case?

I have thought that I could launch an intent from Activity B -> Activity A passing it as an extra an enum corresponding to the desired fragment and that Activity A would handle the received parameter navigating through an action to the corresponding fragment. How do you see it? I think it can be improved and that's why I'm looking for a second solution. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this (your nav host fragment) in both of your activities with

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_pager_host"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="670dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav_graph"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
```

and then in your activity B onCreate() just add

```
val navController = (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_view_pager_host) as NavHostFragment).navController

navController.navigate(/* To your fragment B*/)
//Handle anything else you wanna ddo
```